# Inline css for several elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use inline css because I have some parameters I need to pass which I can't do it in css files. Everything is fine if I set the style for one element, for example :

```
<div class="example" style="background-color:#**<?=$model->color?>**">
```

But because there are lots of elements need that color parameter, can I put all of them in one style?
If in css, I do it like this :

```
.example h1, h2, li, p a {color: red};
```

I'm trying this in inline css but it doesn't work :

```
<div class="example" style="h1, h2, li, p a color:#**<?=$model->theme_color;?>**">
```

Does anyone know how to do this? And may I do it inline?

Comment: Sorry, added php to tags for a moment but then read carefully and it’s not actually PHP specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
<?php
echo "<style>
    .example h1, h2, li, p a {
        color: $model->theme_color
    }
    </style>";
?>
```

Another way:

```
<style>
    .example h1, h2, li, p a {
        color: <?php echo $model->theme_color; ?>;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you probably need is internal CSS (instead of inline CSS) - that's where you include your CSS within style tags. So something like

```
<!-- your external CSS files -->
<style>
   h1, h2, li, p a { color:#**<?=$model->theme_color;?>** }
</style>
<body>
   <!-- your HTML -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not apply classes instead of internal/inline CSS? Something like:

HTML:

```html
<div class="color-<?=$model->color?>">
```

CSS:

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's a great idea! but maybe there'll be a lot of codes in css because there are lots of parameter combinations.

Comment: Well, in that case, using internal (NOT INLINE) CSS is justified and recommended.

Answer (score 2):

***Try this way:***

```php
<?php
 echo "
   <style>
     .example h1, h2, li, p a {
       color: #".$model->theme_color."
     }
   </style>
";
?>
```